# Zend Image Upload validation issue edit page

Tags: image, zend-framework, file-upload, validation

I'm working on `Zend Framework 1.11.12` version. In my add form where we've to put `file upload (for photo upload)` field and it has few `validations as required, file extensions and size specific criteria` mentioned as below, which is declared under my zend form:

```
    // part of my form class (Default_Form_Photo::init)
    $photo = new Zend_Form_Element_File('photo', '', array('required'   => true));
    $photo->setLabel('Photo')
          ->setDestination('/var/www/zendframework/public/uploads/');
    // ensure its mandatory
    #$photo->addValidator('required', true);
    // ensure only one file
    $photo->addValidator('Count', false, array('min' => 1));
    // max 2MB
    $photo->addValidator('Size', false, 2097152)
          ->setMaxFileSize(2097152);
    // only JPEG, PNG, or GIF
    $photo->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg,jpeg,png,gif');
    $photo->setValueDisabled(true);
    $this->addElement($photo, 'photo');
```

Now I have taken a `hidden field`, for `edit page` which will return me current image name, if no new image uploaded:

```
    // hidden element for edit time photo save
    $this->addElement('hidden', 'photo_uploaded', array( ));
```

I set this `hidden element value from controller` by `$form->photo_uploaded->setValue($result['photo'])`.

Now the problem is: when user edit information, it does not allow saving because the `file upload field is blank` as no new image uploaded, but in my case have to use existing current image, which I am passing from hidden element to my controller.

So validation causes problem here, any idea how can i remove validation for my edit page where users do not have to upload new image every time, they are editing information.

Earliest response will be appreciated.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this requires you to add two functions to your form: isValid and getValues.  First of all, remove required from the photo element as we are going to check for this in isValid:

```
/**
 * Check if a photo has been submitted. If not, set the form element as required.
 * @param $data Array of values
 * @return Boolean true if all form element requirements are mets
 */
public function isValid($data)
{
 //A photo has not been uploaded this time, nor previously.
 if(!$data['photo'] AND !$data['photo_uploaded'])
 {
  $this->photo->isRequired(TRUE);
 }
 return parent::isValid($data);
}

/**
 * Return an array of form element values
 * @return Array of values
 */
public function getValues()
{
 $values = $this->getValues();

 //if photo has been uploaded, but no previous photos have been uploaded, then set photo_uploaded value.
 if($values['photo'] AND !$values['photo_uploaded'])
 {
  $values['photo_uploaded'] = $values['photo'];
 }

 //if previous photo has been uploaded, but photo has not been uploaded this time, set photo value
 if($values['photo_uploaded'] AND !$values['photo'])
 {
  $values['photo'] = $values['photo_uploaded'];
 }

 return $values;
}
```